# How do I not show the MuiFormLabel-filled message of previous answers in the Formular?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The code below shows a React, Material-UI Field. I have also added an image to show what it looks like in the browser. Can anyone tell me how not to get this MuiFormLabel-filled message? [Image of the Application where the suggested value is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3lxP.png)

```
 <Field
   filled="false"
   name="landOfBirth"
   type="text"
   fullWidth
   label={lang('landOfBirthLabel')}
   as={DebouncedTextField}
   InputLabelProps={{
       shrink: true,
   }}
/>
```

I tryed to add the property filled="false" to the Field Element as shown in the code but this doesnt change the outcome of getting that suggested message of old input values

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem and include in your question the code needed to reproduce your problem. In its current state, since you aren't showing any imports, we can't tell what `Field` is or what `DebouncedTextField` is.